# It is possible to run the perl script using anchor tag?

Tags: html, perl

My HTML code is

```
<a href="pdbstorage.pl" name="tim">TIM protein</a>
```

My perl script is

```
use CGI;
$cgi = CGI -> new();
$n = $cgi->param ("tim");
print "$n";
```

How to post the `name` into the perl script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the "name" parameter to the link, your html should be

```
<a href="pdbstorage.pl?name=tim" name="tim">TIM protein</a>
```

Note here the "?name=tim"; this portion of the url is known as the *query string*

To read that value, your perl code should be:

```
use CGI;
$cgi = CGI -> new();
$n = $cgi->param ("name");
print "name is $n";
```

You are looking for the value of the "name" parameter, which is "tim".